# Why no semicolon gives errors but too many of them don't?

Tags: c, syntax

Consider this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>;

int main(void) {
    puts("Hello, world!");; ;
    ;
    return 0; ;
    ; ;
};
```

Here I've put semicolons almost everywhere possible. Just for *fun*. But surprisingly [it worked](http://ideone.com/o09SZh)! I got a warning about the semicolon after include but other absolutely wrong semicolons worked. If I forget to put a semicolon after `puts`, I'll get the following error

> error: expected ';' before 'return'

---

*Why don't lots of wrong and useless semicolons cause errors?* To my mind they should be treated as syntax errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A single semicolon constructs a **null statement**. It's not only legal, it's also useful in some cases, for instance, a `while`/ `for` loop that doesn't need a real body. An example:

```
while (*s++ = *t++)
    ;
```

> C11 6.8.3 Expression and null statements
>
> A null statement (consisting of just a semicolon) performs no operations.

---

The only syntax error is this line:

```
#include <stdio.h>;
```

Comment: Then how did it compile if a semicolon after an include is an error?

Comment: @ForceBru Isn't there a warning?

Comment: yes, sure, but it's a warning, not an error, isn't it? So, it's just deprecated but OK.

Comment: @ForceBru A warning doesn't mean it's *deprecated*. I'll say it's more like a small error, not fatal, but a diagnostic messages is necessary.

Comment: @ForceBru The `;` will remain after the include has been resolved by the preprocessor, so it depends on what the included source contains, about it may change the source to become invalid or just be another null statement.

Comment: Take also a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30909009/1938163) - related

Answer (score 5):

semicolon means end of a statement whether it is empty or not. No semicolon means you have not closed/ end last statement but started a new one which gives error. too many semicolon indicates end of blank statement each. So, it does not give error

Answer (score 1):

Why should an empty statement be an error? It is not.

Answer (score 0):

The `;` (statement delimiter) is always used to specify that particular statement is ended. There after next statement is executed.

If you dont put delimeter, then it will consider the next statement with the current statement and execute. And that gives a syntatic error.

But in other case when we put multiple delimeters eg:

`int a;;;;;`

In that case we have 5 statements, in which `int a` is first statement and next four statements are null statements that will be removed by compiler at during compilation.

**See some interesting cases for this question**:

```
int main()
{
    int a=0 ;,;
    return 0;
}
```

when we change above programj it it still works:

```
int main()
{
    int a=0 ,; /*change done*/
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `;` is a statement delimiter in C as mentioned in the above answer. Rahul's answer is perfectly correct, just that you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703395/why-do-most-c-statements-end-with-a-semicolon/34703515#34703515) answer to a question which asks why a statement in C ends with a semicolon. Thus, when you understand why a semicolon is used, you will understand what happens when you put too many semicolons.